# AWS RDS CPU and selects high, nothing is running

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a database cluster on AWS RDS. This is supporting a wordpress website, as well as a custom site and an api connector between them. On this cluster I have the master writer (t2.medium) and a read replica (t2.small). This is running on Aurora MySQL 5.6 compatible.

Both of these instances are averaging 20-30% cpu usage and constantly show activity of about 100 Selects/Sec each. 
Connecting to the mysql instance and checking `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` shows that there is currently nothing running.

Does anyone know what could be causing this or have come across similar before?

The CPU usage has caused all the CPU credits to have been used up and been Aurora, the selects and cpu usage is causing large IOPS which is blowing out the billing costs.

Suggestions to help debug and diagnose this would be greatly appreciated.